# Allow the Time Manager to show map tips

Tags: qgis, timemanager, photos, maptips

I need to measure agricultural fields. I have Points (gpx format) of the perimeter of the  field and geotagged pictures on the same perimeter. 
I use the pictures to verify the measurement.

I already do load in QGIS the polygon shape of the field and point shape of pictures.
I also can use map tips to show the picture as moving above the point, but a field can have more than 100 pictures and is laborious to go with the mouse above each of the points.

I can also use Time Manager to show the picture points as time goes by.
What I would like to do:
is to use the Time Manager to not just show the point (location of the picture) but the map tip too.
At the end I would like an automatic mode to verify easily the field measurement watching (as if it was a film) the points and images show themselves as time goes by.

I'm using QGIS 2.18; Time Manager 2.4.1

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use something similar to what Nathan Woodrow describe here : https://nathanw.net/2016/02/04/live-svgs/ to symbolise your point with your picture then use the time manager make the picture appear at the right time.

Comment: Thank you very much. This could be. I'm trying to guess what do I have to change to use local jpg instead of remote svg

Comment: You have to convert your JPG to SVG as there is no option to use JPG as point marker, when done it's just a matter of symbolisation

Comment: i'm trying but blindly as i have never worked with python, can you help with the python code of the show_camera function?

Comment: You don't really need to use python (and I don't have the skill to help you...), just convert your jpg to svg (there are online tool or you can use inkscape) then use data override to set the path to your svg

Comment: I'm stuck in error: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 30: ordinal not in range(128) (i don't know how to paste here the code of the function in a readable way

Comment: I would edit your original answer with the error you are getting, that way you can build on to the question you have. Otherwise if it a new error, close this question and re-ask a question with the new error. It keeps the QnA focused

Comment: I'm stuck and anyway it's not feasable for me to convert all jpg's to svg's (there are more than 100 for each field measured, in total tens of thousands). My first question was how to make map tips permanently visible to be able to wach to them as if a film with timemanager. Maybe a more natural solution would be to have the image in the label which is always visible. It's maybe a very stupid question, but way does not have label the html capabilities of map tip and map tip be just a special rendering case of label?